# Difficulty pattern matching on equality proof in with statement

Tags: agda, dependent-type, theorem-proving

I am attempting to learn Agda by writing a Monoid library however I am struggling with showing that the composition of two monoid homomorphisms is a monoid homomorphism.

I have defined Monoids as so

```
record Monoid (a : Level) : Set (Level.suc a) where
  field
    Underlying : Set a 
    _◓_ : Underlying → Underlying → Underlying
     : Underlying
  field
    ◓-assoc : (a b c : Underlying) → ((a ◓ b) ◓ c) ≡ (a ◓ (b ◓ c))
    -left-neutral : {a : Underlying} →  ◓ a ≡ a
    -right-neutral : {a : Underlying} → a ◓  ≡ a
```

and Monoid Homomorphisms as

```
record MonHom {L L'} (M : Monoid L) (M' : Monoid L') : Set ( L ⊔ L') where
  open Monoid M
  open Monoid M' renaming (  to '; _◓_ to _◓'_ ; Underlying to Underlying')
  field
    f : Underlying → Underlying'
    -preserved : f  ≡ '
    ◓-preserved : (X Y : Underlying) → (f (X ◓ Y)) ≡ (f X ◓' f Y)
```

The attempt to prove that Monoid Homomorphisms compose requires showing that the Monoid Operation is preserved, which I have attempted to do here:

```
id-pres-comp : ∀ {a b c} {M : Monoid a} {M' : Monoid b}
                 {M'' : Monoid c} {f : MonHom M M'} {g : MonHom M' M''}
                 (X Y : Monoid.Underlying M) →
               MonHom.f g (MonHom.f f ((M Monoid.◓ X) Y)) ≡
               (M'' Monoid.◓ MonHom.f g (MonHom.f f X))
               (MonHom.f g (MonHom.f f Y))
-- (g ∘ f) (X ◓ Y) ≡ ((g ∘ f) X) ◓' ((g ∘ f)
id-pres-comp {a} {b} {c} {M} {M'} {M''}
             {record { f = f1 ; -preserved = id-pres1 ; ◓-preserved = comp-pres1 }}
             {record { f = g2 ; -preserved = id-pres2 ; ◓-preserved = comp-pres2 }}
             X Y with (comp-pres1 X Y)
...| p = {!!}
```

My intuition tells me that pattern matching on preservation proofs for both homomorphisms using `with` statements will make the proof trivial however I seem to be unable to make progress as I cannot match onto `refl` for unknown reasons as described by the error:

```
-- I'm not sure if there should be a case for the constructor refl,
-- because I get stuck when trying to solve the following unification
-- problems (inferred index ≟ expected index):
--   f1 ((M Monoid.◓ X) Y) ≟ (M' Monoid.◓ f1 X) (f1 Y)
-- when checking that the pattern refl has type
-- f1 ((M Monoid.◓ X) Y) ≡ (M' Monoid.◓ f1 X) (f1 Y)
```

Can anyone help me understand this error and help me make progress with this proof?

Thanks!

Full gist [here](https://gist.github.com/alessio-b-zak/01510176f895d1ef07b1199fe3b43895).

Comment: I've solved this by manually rewriting the proof with `cong` and `trans` but I'm still curious as to why the error occurs.